# Como usar o fluent nhibernate apropriadamente?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

Um problema que tenho encontrado por conta da inexperiência com esse tipo de ferramente é COMO usar o lazy load sem interferir na arquitetura do software.

Utilizo a seguinte arquitetura:

**IHM (Interface homem-máquina):** Possui todos os formulários e se comunica com a camada **BLL**

**BLL (Business Logic Layer):** Possui todas as regras de como uma classe deve se comportar, lança todas as exceções para serem exibidas na **IHM**, faz e retorna todo tipo de comando que envolva banco de dados utilizando a camada **DAL**

**DAL (Data Access Layer):** Aqui se encontra o Fluent Nhibernate e aqui faz as consultas.

Tenho lido bastante a respeito do grande ganho de performance quando se usar o **LazyLoad**, porém, não consigo pensar, nem imaginar, como poderia usá-lo sem atrapalhar a arquitetura. Pois, minha IHM não tem acesso a sessão da camada DAL.

Imagine a seguinte situação:

Função da BLL **getVendas()** pede todas as vendas para a camada DAL.
A IHM pega o resultado e exibe os horários das vendas.
Quando o usuário seleciona um horário, deve exibir os produtos vendidos nesta venda. Isto requer um lazy load, mas como fazer isso se a sessão já foi descartada?
É uma má arquitetura? Existe algum outro meio?

**OBS:** Sei que posso desligar o Lazy Load, mas estou questionando a respeito de uma forma de usar o lazyload para melhor performance.

**EDIT**
[image: Tela de visualização de vendas]

**Form OnLoad**

```
    private void FrmVisualizarVenda_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Venda> Vendas;
            if (Acao == AcaoIHMVenda.PorData)
                Vendas = VendaBLL.getVendasDia(DataVenda.Value);
            else
            {
                Vendas = VendaBLL.getVendasCanceladasHoje();
                btnCancelar.Visible = false;
                btnReimpressao.Enabled = false;
            }

            lstVendas.Items.AddRange(Vendas.ToArray());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**List IndexChanged**

```
    public void lstVendas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdProdutos.Rows.Clear();

        VendaEscolhida = new VendaBLL((Venda)lstVendas.SelectedItem);
        Venda v = VendaEscolhida.Venda;

        lblCod.Text = v.CdVenda.ToString();
        lblOp.Text = v.Operador.Nome;

        lblDinheiro.Text = v.Dinheiro.ToString("C2");
        lblDebito.Text = v.Debito.ToString("C2");
        lblCredito.Text = v.Credito.ToString("C2");
        lblVoucher.Text = v.Voucher.ToString("C2");

        lblDesconto.Text = v.Desconto.ToString("C2");
        lblPago.Text = v.ValorPago.ToString("C2");
        lblTroco.Text = v.Troco.ToString("C2");

        foreach (ProdutoVendido pv in v.Vendidos)
        {
            grdProdutos.Rows.Add(
                pv.Produto,
                pv.Quantidade,
                pv.Produto.Valor,
                pv.Total,
                pv.Cortesia
                );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tenho uma dúvida: você está aceitando respostas cujo foco seja na mudança da tecnologia da DAL? Pergunto isso porque o Entity Framework não é baseado no conceito de sessões de dados. Ou seja, os dados só são carregados quando o objeto agregado é efetivamente usado.

Comment: Aceito sim, mas me preocupo fortemente com as outros camadas, elas não podem (não deveriam) mudar.

Comment: @Lizard, a sua duvida seria na hora do clique dos horários ter que abrir novamente a session?

Comment: @HarryPotter não necessariamente, mas é um caso. Acontece que se eu abrir uma nova session, não dá certo (A não ser que eu tenha realizado algum procedimento errado). Enfim, se tiver alguma solução pra todas as situações (Não apenas essa) coloque (:

Comment: @Lizard por isso eu perguntei, porque, isso vai depender muito da maneira como você implementou essa tela, ou até mesmo as classes, como eu trabalho com padrões pra mim não precisa trocar o seu repositório em hibernate (apesar que o Entity Framework é a melhor solução), o que eu precisa ver sinceramente era partes do seu código.

Comment: @HarryPotter Gostaria muito de saber sua proposta, por conta da minha pouca experiência com esse tipo de ferramentas. O que sugere? Que eu post imagem da tela e do código?

Comment: Você pode colocar as duas coisas!!!

Comment: @HarryPotter Feito, o que acha?

Comment: é a forma de fazer no meu entender, porque eu faria diferente e não fecharia a sessão logo de cara, trabalharia com injeção de dependência e resolvia a parte da session, o que eu poderia fazer é um exemplo simples do jeito dessa tela !

Comment: @HarryPotter Se não fosse te atrapalhar e se não estiver muito ocupado, gostaria muito (: mas mudaria muito as camadas?

Comment: @Lizard vou te propor algo mais ai você pode decidir ok!

Comment: @Lizard se precisar do código fonte me mande um e-mail bruxohpotter@gmail.com que eu mando o exemplo completo mais ta ai como eu faria como resposta!

Comment: @HarryPotter Já mandei o e-mail (:

Comment: Logo te mando o zip com aquelas mudança

Comment: Talvez uma sugestão simples e prática seria usar o yield. http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Exemplo:***

***Conexão***

```
public interface IConnection: IDisposable
{
    void Close();
    ISession Open();
    FluentConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    ISessionFactory SessioFactory { get; }
    ISession Session { get; }
}
public class Connection : IConnection
{
    private FluentConfiguration _configuration;
    private ISessionFactory _sessiofactory;
    private ISession _session;

    public FluentConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get { return _configuration; }
        private set { _configuration = value; }
    }
    public ISessionFactory SessioFactory
    {
        get { return _sessiofactory; }
        private set { _sessiofactory = value; }
    }

    public ISession Session
    {
        get { return _session; }
        private set { _session = value; }
    }

    public Connection()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        _configuration = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(x => x
                                                                 .Server("localhost")
                                                                 .Username("root")
                                                                 .Password("senha")
                                                                 .Database("site1")))
        .Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<WindowsFormsApp.Code.Models.Cliente>());
        _sessiofactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
        _session = _sessiofactory.OpenSession();
    }
    public ISession Open()
    {
        if (_session.IsOpen == false)
        {
            _session = _sessiofactory.OpenSession();
        }
        return _session;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        if (_session != null && _session.IsOpen)
        {
            _session.Close();
            _session.Dispose();
        }
        _configuration = null;
        if (_sessiofactory != null && _sessiofactory.IsClosed == false)
        {
            _sessiofactory.Close();
            _sessiofactory.Dispose();
        }
    }
    ~Connection()
    {

    } 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Close();
    }      

}
```

***Repository***

```
public interface IRepository<T>: IDisposable
        where T : class, new()
{
    IConnection Connection { get; }
    void Add(T model);
    void Edit(T model);
    void AddorEdit(T model);
    void Remove(T model);
    T Find(object Key);
    IQueryable<T> Query();
    IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where);
}

using NHibernate.Linq;
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private IConnection _connection;
    public IConnection Connection
    {
        get { return this._connection; }
        private set { this._connection = value; }
    }
    public Repository()
    {
        this._connection = new Connection();
        this.Connection.Open();
    }
    public Repository(IConnection Connection)
    {
        this._connection = Connection;
        this.Connection.Open();
    }

    public void Add(T model)
    {
        this._connection.Session.Transaction.Begin();
        this._connection.Session.Save(model);
        this._connection.Session.Transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Edit(T model)
    {
        this._connection.Session.Transaction.Begin();
        this._connection.Session.SaveOrUpdate(model);
        this._connection.Session.Transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void AddorEdit(T model)
    {
        this._connection.Session.Transaction.Begin();
        this._connection.Session.SaveOrUpdate(model);
        this._connection.Session.Transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Remove(T model)
    {
        this._connection.Session.Transaction.Begin();
        this._connection.Session.Delete(model);
        this._connection.Session.Transaction.Commit();
    }

    public T Find(object Key)
    {
        return (T)this._connection.Session.Get<T>(Key);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query()
    {
        try
        {
            return this._connection.Session.Query<T>();
        }
        catch (NHibernate.ADOException ex)
        {
            var er = ex.Data;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where)
    {
        return this._connection.Session.Query<T>().Where(Where);
    }

    ~Repository()
    {

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection != null)
        {
            _connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

***Classe Mapeadas***

```
//CLIENTE E CLIENTEMAP
public class ClienteMap : ClassMap<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteMap()
    {
        Table("cliente");
        Id(x => x.Codigo).GeneratedBy.Increment().Not.Nullable().Column("codigo");
        Map(x => x.Nome).Nullable().Column("nome");

        HasMany(x => x.Telefone).Cascade.All().LazyLoad().KeyColumn("codigocliente");
    }
}
public class Cliente
{
    public Cliente()
    {
        this.Telefone = new List<Telefone>();
    }

    public virtual int Codigo { get; set; }
    public virtual String Nome { get; set; }       

    public virtual IList<Telefone> Telefone { get; set; }
}
//TELEFONE E TELEFONEMAP
public class TelefoneMap : ClassMap<Telefone>
{
    public TelefoneMap()
    {
        Table("telefone");
        Id(x => x.Codigo).Not.Nullable().UniqueKey("codigo").GeneratedBy.Increment().Column("codigo");
        Map(x => x.Ddd).Not.Nullable().Column("ddd").Length(3);
        Map(x => x.Numero).Not.Nullable().Column("numero").Length(14);

        References(x => x.Cliente).Cascade.All().LazyLoad().Column("codigocliente");
    }
}
public class Telefone
{
    public Telefone() { }
    public virtual int Codigo { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual String Ddd { get; set; }
    public virtual String Numero { get; set; }
}
```

***RepositoryCliente e RepositoryTelefone***

```
public sealed class RepositoryCliente : Repository<Cliente>
{
    public RepositoryCliente() : base() { }
    public RepositoryCliente(IConnection Connection)
        : base(Connection) { }
}
public sealed class RepositoryTelefone : Repository<Telefone>
{
    public RepositoryTelefone() : base() { }
    public RepositoryTelefone(IConnection Connection)
        : base(Connection) { }
}
```

***Bom esse é todo o código que eu geralmente faço, agora como utilizar isso tudo:***
Explicação: Quero mostrar em `ListBox` os `Clientes` e no GridView seus respectivos Telefones

***Form***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Código do Form***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApp.Code;
using WindowsFormsApp.Code.Abstract;
using WindowsFormsApp.Code.Models;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private Repository<Cliente> RepCliente;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataGridFones.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            RepCliente = new RepositoryCliente();

            ListClientes.DataSource = RepCliente.Query().ToList();
            ListClientes.DisplayMember = "Nome";
            ListClientes.ValueMember = "Codigo";

        }

        ~Form1()
        {
            RepCliente.Dispose();
        }

        private void ListClientes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListClientes.SelectedItems.Count > 0 &&
                ListClientes.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                Cliente cliente = RepCliente.Find(((Cliente)ListClientes.SelectedItem).Codigo);
                if (cliente != null)
                {
                    DataGridFones.DataSource = cliente.Telefone.ToList();
                    DataGridFones.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bom com somente `RepositoryCliente` eu consigo resgatar sem fechar a sua sessão e só fecha quando o formulário fechar. Também um ponto pouco código que faz bastante coisa no *form*, e o importante trabalhando com *lazyload* pela configuração dado pelo `framework`.

Sobre a dúvida de várias `Session` aberta, como utilizar 1 para todas as `Repository`

***Exemplo de Codificação:***

```
using (IConnection connection = new Connection())
using (Repository<Cliente> RepClientes = new RepositoryCliente(connection))
using (Repository<Telefone> RepTelefones = new RepositoryTelefone(connection))
{
        //CODIFICAÇÃO           
}
```

***Ou***

```
IConnection connection = new Connection();
Repository<Cliente> RepClientes = new RepositoryCliente(connection);
Repository<Telefone> RepTelefones = new RepositoryTelefone(connection);
//CODIFICAÇÃO   
//CODIFICAÇÃO   
//CODIFICAÇÃO   
RepClientes.Dispose();
RepTelefones.Dispose();
connection.Dispose();
```

*Foi feito então um `connection` que vai servir para dois ou mais `repository`.*

Comment: Gostei muito e vou aderir. Não que a proposta do @Cigano Morrison Mendez seja ruim, é ótima, inclusive pretendo utilizar no futuro. Mas por ora o que vai servir é a sua proposta. Só gostaria de questionar a respeito de três coisas. É obrigatório o destrutor do form? A sua classe connection não corre o risco de ter muitas sessões abertas ao mesmo tempo? Na classe connection aconselharia um metódo Dispose(), ou só o Close() basta?

Comment: Blz, não é. Obrigatório, perceba que pode fazer injeção em vários repositórios vou colocar um exemplo na resposta, vou implementar o dispose pra vc.

Comment: Eu também usaria a idéia com ef

Answer (score 2):

O nHibernate não é bom para carga de dados sob demanda da forma com que você quer, coisa que o Entity Framework faz bem.

No caso do seu `getVendas()`, o Entity Framework realiza a carga da seguinte forma:

- Realiza uma consulta em banco trazendo apenas o primeiro nível de dados (ou seja, objetos do tipo `Models.Venda`;
- As coleções de `Models.Produto` de cada venda recebem cada uma um Proxy Dinâmico, ou seja, um objeto que implementa `ICollection`, mas não é exatamente uma `ICollection`.
- Apenas quando a IHM acessa a coleção de produtos de cada venda os dados são efetivamente carregados. Neste caso, o Entity Framework substitui o `DynamicProxy` pela efetiva coleção de produtos.

O nHibernate cria um complicador para o programador, que é ter que controlar a sessão de dados. É o mesmo problema do Hibernate do Java, em que cada evento da DAO exige que o programador indique quais entidades serão efetivamente carregadas, e de qual forma (*lazy* ou *eager*).

Considere a troca do Framework para não prejudicar a coesão da sua arquitetura.

Em todo caso, se for **realmente** necessário manter o nHibernate, você pode escrever um `ActionFilter` que abra a sessão de dados pra você no momento que julgar necessário. Aí basta marcar os métodos da sua BLL com o `Attribute` deste `ActionFilter` que a sessão de dados será aberta durante a execução do método.

Comment: Só aproveitando, pois nunca conheci o EF, ele funciona parecido com o nhibernate? No sentido de uma classe para propriedade e outra para mapeamento? Vi que essa EF é da microsoft, dá pra utiliza-la com um banco MySql?

Comment: Funciona bem parecido. A de mapeamento não precisa: ele é mais simples de configurar. Tem este artigo introdutório em português: http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-mysql-com-ado-net-entity-framework-4-parte-i/21667. É um pouco antigo, mas é um bom ponto de partida.