# duvida ao fazer mapeamento nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
public class ExemploDTO
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PessoaDTO> Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual ServicoDTO Servico { get; set; }
}
```

Como seria o mapeamento dessa classe usando:
`NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist` ou `Fluentnhibernate`

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22354/como-usar-o-fluent-nhibernate-apropriadamente?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando Fluent ficaria assim:

```
public class ExemploMap : ClassMap<ExemploDTO>
{
    public ExemploMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        .Length(10)
        .Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.ServicoDTO);
        HasMany(x => x.PessoaDTO);
    }
}
```

Te aconselho a dar uma olhada [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/14/09/c_fmap1.htm), [aqui](http://www.leandroprado.com.br/2012/01/comecando-com-fluent-nhibernate/) e [aqui](http://notherdev.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html),
com certeza vai clarear tuas ideias. E, se tu estiver começando agora, dá uma olhada no ActiveRecord.

Comment: Lembrando que é preciso mapear a tabela, então antes de Id, colocar Table("Owner.TableName");